# how to hide url value when i using href to pass value?

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to filter my URL value become hidden due to security purpose. Any solution or method to do that?

I'm doing it this way:

```
<html
    <a href='www.iluvpromo.com/unsubscribe.php?email=$email'> 
</html>
```

and the URL is displayed like this:

```
http://www.iluvpromo.com/unsubscribe.php?email="email_address"
```

but I want it to be displayed like this:

```
http://www.iluvpromo.com/unsubscribe.php
```

Comment: Use `Post` Method in php in redirect to a different url

Comment: but whole code is not a form. it is a email template.

Comment: Why don't you want the user to know their own email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use some encryption code to encrypt your parameter which cannot understand by user.

```
$myData = array('foo'=>1, 'bar'=>'hax0r');
$arg = base64_encode( json_encode($myData) );
```

http:www.iluvpormo.com/parameter=$arg

and back:

```
$myData = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['secret'] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) :

in the first page :

```
<?php
 session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$email;
?>
```

in the second page :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
//do sth
//unset($_SESSION['email']); to destroy the session
```

---

another way is to use post variable :

in the first pge :

```
$_POST['email'] = $email;
```

in the second page:

```
if( $_POST["email"])
//do something
```

---

another way is using `hlink` :

```
echo hlink ("hyperlinktext", "email", "http://www.iluvpromo.com/unsubscribe.php", "funkyclass",     $email);
```

instead of this:

```
<a href='http://www.iluvpromo.com/unsubscribe.php?email=$email' class='funkyclass'>hyperlink text</a>
```

Comment: there has no way to hide href value?

Comment: There is no way to hide anything from the user while giving it to the user's browser.

Comment: Not the way you want. Indeed ?param is aimed at get requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can do similar 'action' in several ways:

- md5(email), and user wont see it in cleartext
- you can use session (if user is logged in)
- pass user id (not that good idea thou, users can guess that easily)
- make a POST request with params (not link, form is used for that)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could encrypt your querystring or post the value in a form (visible in source though).

Comment: means that can be only use encrypt?